# Angular2. Method in component is being called multiple times and returns the wrong data

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-services

I have a method inside a module that is being called 3 times when the page load and it returns the wrong data. When debugging / checking the console it appears as the right data is being returned but on the screen the data is wrong

in component.html i have

```
<p ng-if="posting">
 {{ getPlaceholderText('headline') }}
</p>
```

This is the method:

```
getPlaceholderText(placeholderName: string): string {

console.log('Looking for placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '"');

if (this.posting.placeholders != null) {

  this.posting.placeholders.forEach(placeholder => {
    if (placeholder.name === placeholderName) {
      console.log('found placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '"');
      console.log('Returning value: "' + placeholder.text + '"');
      console.log('');
      return placeholder.text;
    }
  });
} else {
  return 'posting.placeholder is null';
}

console.log('');
console.log('placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '" not found');
return 'placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '" not found';
}
```

When the pages is rendered this is output:

```
placeholder with name "headline" not found
```

It should have been the value of placeholder.text property. In the console I have this:

```
Looking for placeholder with name "headline"
found placeholder with name "headline"
Returning value: "Standard Post 1 headline"

placeholder with name "headline" not found

Looking for placeholder with name "headline"
found placeholder with name "headline"
Returning value: "Standard Post 1 headline"

placeholder with name "headline" not found
```

Anyone can put some light on what is going on here?

Here is the complete code for my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Posting } from '../models/Posting';
import { SiteService } from '../shared/siteService/siteService.service';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  version: string = environment.version;
  postingId: number;
  sub: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  posting: Posting;
  postingTitle: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title,
    private siteService: SiteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.isLoading = true;
    this.posting = new Posting();

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.postingId = +params['id'];
      this.postingTitle = params['title'];

      this.titleService.setTitle(this.postingTitle);

      this.siteService.getPost({ id: this.postingId })
        .pipe(finalize(() => { this.isLoading = false; }))
        .subscribe(posting => this.posting = posting);
    });
  }

  getPlaceholderText(placeholderName: string): string {

    console.log('Looking for placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '"');

    if (this.posting.placeholders != null) {

      this.posting.placeholders.forEach(placeholder => {
        if (placeholder.name === placeholderName) {
          console.log('found placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '"');
          console.log('Returning value: "' + placeholder.text + '"');
          console.log('');
          return placeholder.text;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return 'posting.placeholder is null';
    }

    console.log('placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '" not found');
    return 'placeholder with name "' + placeholderName + '" not found';
  }
}
```

Comment: try to test the getPlaceholderText() function by returning some static data to debug.

Comment: If you look at the console output it does return the correct data. Its like that return statement has no effect why it continues executing the rest of the method.

Comment: If the above doesn't work then just use <p> {{ getPlaceholderText('headline') }} </p> without setting the condition

Comment: thx, but makes no difference

Comment: Can you share it on jsfiddle as it will be easy to debug

Comment: I am not sure I can. It is a part of a typescript project, with many different files and rest calls etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160510/discussion-between-mahavir-munot-and-tony-fabian).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: 
`<p *ngIf="posting"> {{ getPlaceholderText('headline') }} </p>`

Answer (score 0):

ahhh "forEach" is not TypeScript. It is javascript, so

```
this.posting.placeholders.forEach(placeholder => {
```

should be

```
for (const placeholder of this.posting.placeholders) {
```

and then it works